# Removing words from a sentence before a keyword from a specific list

Tags: python, string, nlp

I have a list of keywords `keywords = [",", "or", "and"]`
and a sentence `s = built on the kernel, is written largely in`

I want to remove all the words from the above sentence before any keyword from the above list, in this case "," . So the Output will be `is written largely in.`

Comment: and what will be desired string in case of multiple keywords in the string like `"Hello, and, or, Stack Overflow"`?

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

keywords = [",", "or", "and"]
s = "built on the kernel, is written largely in"
split_sentence = re.split(',|or|and',s)[1:]
result = "".join(split_sentence)
print(result)
```

output:

```
is written largely in
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) with *pattern* as `|` joined string of your `keywords`. It will return you list of strings separated by your keywords. Since you need the last sub-string from the `list`, you can access it using `-1` as index.

For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> keywords = [",", "or", "and"]
>>> my_str = "Hello, and, or, Stack Overflow"

>>> re.split('|'.join(keywords), my_str)[-1]
' Stack Overflow'
```

Additionally, if you want to remove additional white spaces from the resultant string, then you can further use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) on the above string as:

```
>>> re.split('|'.join(keywords), my_str)[-1].strip()
'Stack Overflow'
```